# How can I hide the navigation back button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```swift
navigationBarBackButtonHidden(_ hidesBackButton: Bool) -> some View
```

But it still shows the back button and I want to remove the back function when clicked.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show more code? (Maybe even fort it as code?) It would be helpful for us to duplicate your issue.

Answer (score 100):

Maybe:

```
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

Comment: Works with XCode 12.1

Answer (score 25):

I tried placing `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` in a few different places. This is the behaviour I observed.

```
struct PageOne: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: PageTwo()){
                    Text("Go to Page Two")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Hide from page 2 -> page 1
struct PageTwo: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: PageThree()){
                Text("Go to Page Three")
            }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

// Hide from page 3 -> page 2 (Same behaviour as Kheldar's answer above)
struct PageTwo: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: PageThree().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)){
                Text("Go to Page Three")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PageThree: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Using via a navigationLink

```
NavigationLink(destination: SomePage().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
    //..
}
```

The `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` will hide the back button.

Comment: I am still slightly irritated that I have to place this in every navigation link. but writing it in the link is much neater than placing it at the bottom of the view implementation.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me. I'm running Xcode 14.2 with iOS 16

Comment: @CDMsocialmediasinbio welcome to the absolute shitshow of SwiftUI... it doesn't get better from here.

Answer (score 19):

This is the solution, but it doesn't work on Xcode 11 beta 4:

```
struct LiveView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: ButtonView()) {
                Text("Next screen")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    @State var navigationBarBackButtonHidden = true

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show back") {
            self.navigationBarBackButtonHidden = false
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(navigationBarBackButtonHidden)
    }
}
```

There is also `navigationBarHidden` which doesn't work on the iPhone, but it works perfectly on [watchOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WatchOS).

Comment: This is the most helpful, complete solution

Answer (score 14):

I encountered a situation where I couldn't get the `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` to work until I placed it on the View that I embedded within the `NavigationLink` itself.

```
NavigationLink(destination:MyView(stuff: aStuff, onDismiss: {})) {
         HStack {
             Text(aStuff.interestingText)
         }
} // <- used to set it here, doesn't work for me
```

with:

```
struct MyView: View {

    var aStuff: Stuff
    var onDismiss: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
          VStack(alignment: .leading) {
               Button(action: self.onDismiss) {
                   Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle")
               }
               CoolAnimatedStuffDisplayer(stuff: aStuff)
          }
          .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) // <--- works here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```swift
VStack{
 //content...
}
.toolbar(.hidden)
```

to hide the toolbar completely

Comment: I need to mention that it is for iOS16 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` just after the

destination like this :

`NavigationLink("Next", destination:  SecondView()).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).