# hide back button title on navigation bar not working for iOS 13 and above

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have added the following code to hide the back button title on the navigation bar but it is not working on iOS 15.

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: -1000, vertical: 0),
                                                                      for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

can someone help me plz?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hide the navigation back button in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112026/how-can-i-hide-the-navigation-back-button-in-swiftui)

Comment: No, it's for swift UI my code is in swift.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all navigationbar back button title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912489/how-to-remove-all-navigationbar-back-button-title)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do this on your navigation bar button:

```
 navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

The title will need to be an empty string and that gets rid of the title.

Comment: Tried not working.

Comment: Is the title still there? And do you call this is viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this by using following method :

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()    
appearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: -1000, vertical: 0)
```